# Fasttext: How to process a corpora with fasttext?

Tags: corpus, fasttext

I'm new to fasttext and NLP. I have a corpora `csv` in **french** structured as follow:

```
| value | sentence                       | pivot    |
|-------|--------------------------------|----------|
| 1     | My first [sentence]            | sentence |
| 0     | My second [word] in a sentence | word     |
| ..    | ...                            | ...      |
```

I want to know how to tell fasttext to process the pivot words between brackets `[pivot]` to build my model, or is it a feature built-in in fasttext that he knows which word to process ? I really want to know the mechanics about fasttext ! the documentation I found is limited. Thanks.

Comment: I want to understand better...

What is your aim?

You want to predict words in pivot column, given the sentence?

Anyway, I suggest to read the tutorials:
https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html
https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html

Comment: @Anakin87 thank you for your comments, I made a typo error above on the data sample, the first column taking 0 or 1, `1` if a sentence is a pointing on a road, `0` if not. In this case I am in supervised learning, I did read tutorials and was able to build my model changing my first column to `__label__0` or `__label__1` using only two column of my dataset. with a sample of 512 rows I got a precision 0.27 and recall 0.27

Answer (score 0):

You can extract word vectors of pivot column using fastText in this way:

```
!git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
!cd fastText
!pip install fastText
import fasttext.util
fasttext.util.download_model('fr', if_exists='ignore')  # French
model = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')

vectors = []
dataset = pd.read_csv('path to csv file', sep='\t')
for data in dataset.pivot:
    vectors.append(model[data])
```

https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html